# Storing decryptable passwords for automatied usage

Tags: python, database, sqlite, security, microservices

### TLDR

I am making a REST Session management solution for industrial automation purposes and need to automatically log into devices to perform configurations.

**NOTE**:

These devices are 99% of the time going to be isolated to private networks/VPNs (i.e., Will not have a public IP)

### Dilemma

I am being tasked with creating a service that can store hardware device credentials so automated configurations (& metrics scraping) can be done. The hardware in question only allows REST Session logins via a POST method where the user and (unencrypted) password are sent in the message body. This returns a Session cookie that my service then stores (in memory).

The service in question consists of:

- Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) server
- FastAPI python backend
- SQLITE3 embedded file DB

### Storing Credentials?

My background is not in Security so this is all very new to me but it seems that I should prefer storing a hash (e.g., bcrypt) of my password in my DB for future verification **however** there will **not** be any future verification as this is all automated.

This brings me to what seems like is the only solution - hashing the password and using that as the salt to encrypt the password, then storing the hashed password in the DB for decryption purposes later. I know this provides almost 0 security given the DB is compromised but I am at a loss for alternate solutions. Given the DB is embedded, maybe there is some added assurance that the server **itself** would have to be compromised before the DB itself is compromised? I don't know if there is a technical "right" approach to this, maybe not, however if anyone has any advice I am all ears.

Comment: This should be discussed with the project manager / representatives from the business.  The business has to decide the level of security / risk.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a hardware security module (HSM). There are cloud alternatives (like AWS Secrets manager, an encrypted secrets repository based on keys stored in an actual HSM, AWS KMS). Or if your app is not hosted in a public cloud, you can consider buying an actual HSM too, but that's expensive. So it all comes down to the risk you want to accept vs the cost.

You can also consider building architecture to properly protect your secrets. If you build a secure secrets store service and apply appropriate protection (which would be too broad to describe for an answer here), you can at least provide auditing of secret usage, you can implement access control, you can easily revoke secrets, you can monitor usage patterns in that component and so on. Basically your secrets service would act like a very well protected "HSM", albeit it might not involve specialized hardware at all. This would not guarantee that secrets (secret encryption keys, typically) cannot ever be retrieved from the service like a real HSM would, but it would have many of the benefits as described above.

However, do note that applying appropriate protection is the key there - and that's not straightforward at all. One approach that you can take is model your potential attackers, list ways (attack paths) for compromising different aspects of different components, and then design protections against those, as long as it makes sense financially.